# Sum Columns with Macro

Tags: excel, vba, sum

I am trying to copy figures from one Excel sheet and paste the sum of the figures onto another Excel sheet corresponding to its value.

Copy sum cells `B20:R20` and find next empty cell in  paste onto another sheet column C on to next empty cell

[image: Screenshot]

[image: paste sheet]

Comment: Welcome to [so]! At this site you are expected to try to **write the code yourself**. After **[doing more research](//meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/261592)** if you have a problem you can **post what you've tried** with a **clear explanation of what isn't working** and providing a [**Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example**](//stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). I suggest reading "[ask]" and "[the perfect question](http://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2010/08/29/writing-the-perfect-question/). Also, be sure to take the [tour] and read **[this](//meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/347937/)**.

Comment: I'm not sure this is a programming question.

Answer (score 1):

Here's a simple example showing basic code related what you're asking. It's just to get you started, and you'll need to modify for your situation

```
Sub copyVals()
Dim r As Range, r2 As Range, sh As Worksheet, sh2 As Worksheet
Set sh = Worksheets("1")
Set sh2 = Worksheets("2")
Set r = sh.Range("S2")
r.formula = "=sum(B2:R2)"
sh2.Activate
Set r2 = sh2.Range("C1").End(xlDown).Offset(1, 0)
Application.CutCopyMode = False
r.copy
r2.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues, Operation:=xlNone, SkipBlanks _
        :=False, Transpose:=False
End Sub
```